# Facebook Api for blackbery10

Tags: blackberry-10

Hi friends I am new to blackberry10 platform. I am developing an application to share a page in Facebook. I have done this in blackberry 6, but I didn't get any API support for Facebook in Blackberry10. Can anybody please help me to share page to Facebook in Blackberry10

Answer (score 0):

I recommand to wait for the gold release for the Hub to be functionnal. With the beta4 will stil don't have the Hub application.

Comment: When you launch the emulator or use the dev Alpha, it is the screen of the left which aggregate Mail, Sms, Facebook, twitter, ...

Comment: I am also waiting for the Hub

Answer (score 0):

you can try this Qt facebook graph library, http://code.google.com/p/facebook-cpp-graph-api/